# Error when using the 'distance' function of the package 'move'

Tags: r, function, package

I am having a reoccuring error with the move package, where I cannot use the `distance` function. When I first load the package, I am given the warning

"multiple methods tables found for ‘distance’".

Later, when following the [move vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/move/vignettes/move.html#plotting), I run the line of code:

`distance(leroy)[1:5]`

and am given the error:

"Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘distance’ for signature ‘"Move", "missing"’".

In applying this code to my own dataset, I receive the same error. I assumed this was because R was using a different package for 'distance', however when I directly call it through `move::distance(leroy)` or even `terra::distance(leroy)` I still receive the same error. I have tried reinstalling the package and the 'terra' and 'raster' packages that move requires; my laptop (Mac), RStudio, and all other packages are updated. Gdal is updates, along with geos and proj. I have run the code on a different laptop, as well as on rdrr.io, and it runs perfectly there, so I am assuming the issue is with my laptop. `?move::distance()` shows me the [function description](https://rdrr.io/cran/move/man/distance.html), where x is a move, movestack, or moveburst object. Both the dataset 'leroy' downloaded from Movebank and my own dataset are move objects. Has anyone else run in to a similar problem or have any troubleshooting suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The move package has not updated to account for raster now requiring terra. I downloaded the move package source from [CRAN](http://%20https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=move) (move_4.0.6.tar.gz) and ran their code for the distance function after loading the move package in to R. The code for their distance method is:

```
#setGeneric("distance")#, function(x){standardGeneric("distance")})

setMethod("distance", 
      signature=c(x=".MoveTrackSingle",y="missing"),
      definition=function(x){ 
    Dists<-raster::pointDistance(x[-sum(n.locs(x)),], x[-1,], longlat=isLonLat(x))
        return(Dists)
      })
setMethod("distance", 
      signature=c(".MoveTrackStack",y="missing"), 
      definition=function(x){
        lst <- lapply(split(x), distance)
        return(lst)
      })
```